# Best External REST API Access Pattern?

Tags: c#, rest, design-patterns, decorator

I work on a couple of projects that connect with external services like Facebook and Netflix.  At this moment most libraries I'm using to access these APIs ( including the ones I've written myself ) have single methods so call specific API functions yet always seem to call some sort of base method to make the request.  Something like this:

```
public class ExternalApi
{
    public string SendMessage( criteria )
    {
         //do something unique to this method with criteria like
         //like generating an xml statement or fql query

         return SendRestRequest( modifiedCriteria );
    }

    public string GetData( criteria )
    {
         //do something unique to this method with criteria like
         //like generating an xml statement or fql query

         return SendRestRequest( modifiedCriteria );
    }

    public string SendRestRequest( modifiedCriteria )
    {
         //add global things to modifiedCriteria like authentication bits
         //or wrapping the criteria in some xml or json shell

        var request = new HttpRequest();
        //make the request, return data
    }
}
```

So my question is there a better pattern or OO principal to use here so in each singular API call method I'm not explicitly calling a base method every time?

Is what I'm looking for some kind of invocation interception pattern, like the ASP.NET MVC framework and ActionResults?

Edit 1: I'm not looking to use the features of any other service or library like Wcf.  For these projects I'm only using 1-5% of these API's capabilities and prefer to roll my own code for these things.

Answer (score 4):

Here is a good sample:

[REST and POX](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa395208.aspx) at MSDN

Also take a look at [WCF REST Starter Kit Preview 2](http://aspnet.codeplex.com/Release/ProjectReleases.aspx?ReleaseId=24644) at CodePlex, there should be coding samples related to REST client

And here: [REST in Windows Communication Foundation (WCF)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/netframework/cc950529.aspx)

This one could also be helpfull: [Sample Client Libraries for REST APIs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd179456.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

I had to put together a REST Client for one of my degree assignments. I went with a tiered approach and tried to apply the facade pattern to abstract the details

```
interface HTTPRequest{
  public void get();
  public void post();
  public void put();
  public void delete();
}
```

HTTPRequest provided the basic HTTP functionality, i then created RestClient

```
interface RestClient{
  public void create();
  public void read();
  public void update();
  public void delete();
}
```

This gave me a more CRUD like interface. What i then did was to construct a basic RestClient class that could be subclassed to add custom functionality. Each function had a respective callback function that it called before it returned it's data to the caller. This was named something like "createResultProcessor", this could over written in a subclass of RestClient, to provide Custom Result parsing etc.

Never thought i would say this as i've made enough UML diagrams for a lifetime, but SO could really do with some UML diagram facilities!